# getting Build warning while running yarn build

Tags: reactjs, build, yarn-lock.json

I create build of my react JS project by running "yarn build" and while creating build I get warning  "File sizes after gzip:    717.01 kB  build\static\js\main.85d9885a.js   58.24 kB   build\static\css\main.37788f6b.css   1.78 kB    build\static\js\787.0c3f432a.chunk.js  The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended. Consider reducing it with code splitting:" and after build has been created I run that build but it display a blank page.

I am facing this issue even after I uninstall various packages and libraries which I did not need.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.